# Vim Weird indentation for .html.erb

Tags: vim, indentation

I am typing in my .html.erb file and I realize this weird behaviour of vim indentation.

```
<p>
  <strong>Expires On:</strong>
  <%= @item.expires_on %>
</p>
```

How come when I press enter after `</p>` this happens?

```
<p>
  <strong>Expires On:</strong>
  <%= @item.expires_on %>
  </p>
  _ <= new cursor space
```

Note that I do have `filetype indent on`.

Answer (score 4):

Vim's default html indentation doesn't indent `<p>` tags. This means that, not only would it not remove a level of indent after `</p>`, but it also probably doesn't add a level of indent automatically after the opening `<p>`. If that's the case, you can change this behaviour by setting the variable `g:html_indent_tags`. It should contain a regular expression that matches the tag's name. For example:

```
let g:html_indent_tags = 'p\|li\|nav'
```

This will add a level of indent for the `p`, `li` and `nav` tags. If you want the `<p>` tags only, just set it to "p":

```
let g:html_indent_tags = 'p'
```

If vim really *is* indenting the initial `<p>`, then it's possible that your `indentkeys` option doesn't contain the ">" character. You can check its contents by executing `set indentkeys`. If it doesn't contain `<>>`, you could add it in `.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
setlocal indentkeys+=<<>
```

**EDIT**:

Unfortunately, vim seems to unlet that variable... This doesn't make sense to me at all, but one thing you could do is add that variable assignment to `.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` instead. This should do the trick. Personally, I've done something different -- I've copied the default file to `.vim/indent/html.vim` and commented out the lines that remove the variable. Still, using the `after` directory is probably a better idea.

**EDIT**:

The [html5](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) plugin seems not to suffer from this issue. It could be a good idea to just install that instead. Otherwise, the `g:html_indent_tags` variable is still the place to go, but the best place for it is probably `~/.vim/after/indent/html.vim`:

```
let g:html_indent_tags .= '\|p\|nav\|othertags'
```

Note the usage of `.=` instead of `=`. This is in-place concatenation. You need it, since the variable already exists at this point and you don't want to delete it.

Comment: Weird I put let g:html_indent_tags = 'p\|li\|nav' in my .vimrc but it has no effect but then when I actually run it in the vim window it works. Where should I put this?

Comment: Er, right, seems there's a bit of a problem with this solution. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I set that variable (and doing `:let g:html_indent_tags` shows that it hasn't been unlet), but it's still not indenting `<p>` tags or `<li>` tags.

Comment: Vim unlets the variable, but also lets it again afterwards to assign a pattern to it that looks like the example I gave. Even if the variable exists, it may not have the correct value. If it doesn't start with `p\|li\|nav`, then it won't indent these tags.

To resolve this, you could copy the default file to your `~/.vim/indent/html.vim` and delete the `unlet`, like I explained above. To make it easier, here is the tweaked file in my own vimfiles: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/Vimfiles/blob/master/indent/html.vim. Using this, you should be able to set `g:html_indent_tags` to whatever you need

Comment: Your recommended HTML5 plugin really does the trick for me as a HTML5 and .erb user. Thanks!

Comment: I've installed https://github.com/othree/html5.vim and it solved the problem alone. No other changes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tim Pope has an excellent Vim plugin that adds indentation for things missing by default. https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag

Comment: He has a whole set of useful Vim plugins. `vim-rails` is extremely powerful; I also use `vim-ruby` `vim-bundler` `vim-sleuth` and `vim-unimpaired`.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this question via the Almighty Google.

To complement on what Andrew said above, for those of you on OSX you might want to take a peek at /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/html.vim and the modifications necessary should become evident.

I can't believe I spent so much time suffering from poorly indented <li>s!

Comment: "modifications necessary should become evident"...  you couldn't provide a code sample? I made the modifications that I assumed were necessary and no dice. Maybe it's because I use Janus, though...?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. You just add `call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('li')`, `call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('p')`, etc :). You have to make sure Janus/Your Vimrc isn't loading a different html indent file, however.